# Не работает инпут перемещения с помощью мыши при компиляции игры в html

Tags: c#, unity3d

При компиляции сцены для html, и запуске ее не работает перемещение обьекта по клику мыши в указанное место, в редакторе работает, если компилировать для пк тоже работает, в чем причина не пойму, помогите пожалуйста.

```
 void Update()
{
    if (Play && !Spoil && !isHooking && Touched())
    {
        Vector3 pos = GetTouchWorldPosition();
        if (OnHookArea(pos))
        {
            fishes = new List<InteractFish>();
            isHooking = true;
            CountSpoil = 0;
            StartCoroutine(Hooking(pos));
            Debug.Log("Hooking");
        }
    }
}

`Vector3 GetTouchWorldPosition()
    {
        Vector2 touchPos = GetTouchPosition();
        Vector3 worldPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPos);
        worldPos.z = 0f;
        return worldPos;
    }

    Vector2 GetTouchPosition()
    {
        if (Input.touchSupported)
        {
            return Input.GetTouch(0).position;
        }
        else
        {
            return Input.mousePosition;
        }
    }`
```

Comment: где здесь HTML?

Comment: @aepot как я понимаю, Zend скомпилировал игру в HTML5, в Untiy есть такая возможность. А вот приложить результирующий HTML было бы не плохо)

Comment: iiKuzmychov Вы правильно поняли. Я просто не знал что есть какая то разница в управлении между скомпилированными html и exe клиентами.Пытался найти что нибудь почитать на эту тему, но все не то.